# withTrashed on hasManyThrough relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can `withTrashed` be applied on a `hasManyThrough` relation ?

```
$this->hasManyThrough('App\Message', 'App\Deal')->withTrashed();
```

returns

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()

when i'm doing:

```
$messages = Auth::user()->messages()->with('deal')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();`
```

Here is my Deal model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Deal extends Model
{

    use SoftDeletes;

    /* ... */

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function messages() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message'); // I've tried to put withTrashed() here, there is no error but it doesn't include soft deleting items.
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using `SoftDeletes` trait also in `Message` model?

Comment: No, messages are never deleted

Comment: in this line `->hasManyThrough('App\Message', 'App\Deal')->withTrashed()` you request messages with deleted messages, and you are not using `SoftDelete` trait that's why the exception thrown, you have to remove `withTrashed` function

Comment: How can I required Messages wich belong to deleted Deal ?

Comment: I found that there is no way to do it in this way, I add an answer maybe it will help you

Answer (score 13):

To all those coming to this late, there is now a native way of doing this with Laravel.

```
$this->hasManyThrough('App\Message', 'App\Deal')->withTrashedParents();
```

This is not well documented but can be found in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough`

Comment: This was implemented in Laravel 7.x. Its not available for Laravel 5 or 6

Answer (score 2):

The error is thrown because you are requesting a messages with deleted ones without using `SoftDelete` trait in `Message` model.

After I check the `hasManyThrough` relation code I found that there is no way to do it in this way, you should play around.

Ex:

get the deals of user with messages instead

```
$deals = Auth::user()->deals()->withTrashed()->with('messages')->get();
foreach($deals as $deal) {
     //Do your logic here and you can access messages of deal with $deal->messages
}
```